# Why am I getting error: Method get not found in Illuminate\Routing\Route in my Laravel project?

Tags: laravel-5, routes, phpstorm, vhosts

I made a php file in directory: `resources/views/layouts` named `admin.blade.php`

I tried to attach bootstrap files and styles to this file but I got error cannot resolve file...

Anyway I tried to make my admin panel so created directory `resources/views/admin/dashboard/index.blade.php` and put some code in for extending.
Now I tried to make a route in directory `Routes/web.php` to call my admin panel like this:

```
Route::get('/admin' ,function(){
   return view('admin.dashboard.index');
});
```

```
@extends('layouts.admin')
@section('content')
@endsection
```

for my admin panel.

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/admin' , function() {
    return view('admin.dashboard.index');
});
```

for routing to admin panel

And my virtual hosts:

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin admin@laramarket.dev
        DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/laramarket/public"
        ServerName laramarket.dev
        ErrorLog "logs/laramarket.dev-error.log"
        CustomLog "logs/laramarket.dev-access.log" common
    </VirtualHost>
```

So I have 2 problems actually 3:

1. My bootstrap files cannot resolve in my admin panel
2. My `route/web.php` got error "Method get not found in Illuminate\Routing\Route"
3. I can't search my virtualhost:laramarket.dev in any browser I tried to but it says refuse to connect! I only can handle it from address localhost.

Comment: Use https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper to get better code completion/analysis for Laravel code in PhpStorm. Also check this: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/laravel.html Works fine here from 1st attempt.

Comment: *"I can't search my virtualhost:laramarket.dev in any browser"* have you added it into your `hosts` file?

Comment: of course i did heres :127.0.0.1  laramarket.dev

Comment: <VirtualHost laramarket.dev:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/laramarket/public"
    ServerName laramarket.dev
</VirtualHost>
give this a try

Comment: @Ruchi i tried your advices but now it opens xampp for me 
laramarket.dev is still unreachable and when i triy to use localhost it opens xampp dashboard

Comment: Did you change APP_URL in .env file to http://laramarket.dev ?

Comment: Which browser is used? `.dev` is a REAL domain now and does not work in Google Chrome for sure for 2 years or so now (Chrome will ignore `hosts` for this and will look at real domain name instead -- they own/manage `.dev` tld). Use another tld, e.g. `.test` or `.local`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for virtual host change your virtual host as below.

```
<VirtualHost localhost:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost dev.laramarket.test:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/laramarket/public"
    ServerName dev.laramarket.test
</VirtualHost>
```

In host file

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       dev.laramarket.test
```

in .env file

```
APP_URL=http://dev.laramarket.test
```

For css and js

```
<link href= "{{ asset('css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet>
<link href= "{{ asset('css/bootstrap2.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet>
<script src="{{ asset('js/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>
```

Comment: oh thanks it worked for me,Vielen Dank! :)
but 1 problem is still insists :( i cant attach bootstrap stylesheets and js file
i'd got error file not resolved!somehow phpstorm dosent recognize them!

Comment: mention your code for attaching stylesheet and js file

Comment: <link href= "/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href= "/css/bootstrap2.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

i put bootstrap.min.css&bootstrap2.min.css in directory : public/css 
and bootstrap.min.js in directory :public/js

Comment: sorry i was trying define php variable $path and put it into style href but didnt worked...so i cant waste your time any more i guess i should work on it...thanks again and tell what should i do to upvote your answer?

Comment: i tried this : <link href= "{{ public_path('css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
but its not working!
when i used this:<link href= "/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
it works but i want it rtl not ltr